# SSIS Rename files by replacing part of filename

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, script-task, foreach-loop-container

[Remove the circled part of the filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC5Hu.png)

There are two types of files in folder x:\abc\sales\
one is a compressed .gz file and the other is uncompressed .txt file
My aim is to rename all the ".txt" files:(leaving the .gz files untouched)
Eg. "accn_adjustments_201802020147.txt"

The part after the underscore is basically date and time, the time is not always "0147", it could be "0148" or "0210" or anything else, but always 4 digits...
My task is to remove the last 4 digits so the end result would look something like "accn_adjustments_20180202.txt"

I would think either for-each loop or script task can help me solve this issue but I don't know how to go about it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Add a `Foreach Loop Container` to the package (Drag Foreach Loop Container from the Containers in the SSIS Toolbox on to the package work area).

Step 2) Double click the Foreach Loop to open the Editor

Step 3) Click Collection on the left menu, then change the `Enumerator` property to `Foreach File Enumerator`

Step 4) Choose your Folder: `x:\abc\sales\`

Step 5) Change the property of Files: to `*.txt`

Additionally you will need:

Step 6) Drag the `File System Task` from the toolbox into the `Foreach Loop Container`

Step 7) Double click the `File System Task` and change the Operation to `Rename File`

Step 8) Set the source and target connection on the task (I assume you know how to create those).

Now the container will only loop through text files in the folder.

This can be extended for your purposes by using Variables, the Variable Mappings section of the Foreach Loop and Expressions to dynamically modify the file names and change the connection property of the text file data source. Although I'm not 100% clear exactly what else you need, this should at least answer this question to get you started.

Some additional reading to help with the renaming process:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6c6e4fba-be40-4c53-ab8e-348ccd39c687/rename-file-using-file-system-task-editor?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Make two sources. And use a variable to change the connection property of the second one (the "destination"). The link I posted has a good explanation.

Comment: Hey Jacob, I had a ForeachLoop already but it wouldnt work because I was using the same variable in source and destination. This was causing the variable to lock error out.
I was using var(UnzFile) as source and
REVERSE(REPLACE(REVERSE( var(UnzFile)), LEFT(REVERSE( var(UnzFile) ), 8), "txt.")) as destination

Instead I just created a new variable var(UnzFileDateRemoved)
and put the formula as REVERSE(REPLACE(REVERSE( var(UnzFile) ), LEFT(REVERSE( var(UnzFile) ), 8), "txt."))
Then used var(UnzFile) as Source and var(UnzFileDateRemoved) as Destination variable

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it sorted out :)